# javascript modal popup keep populating only first item data on all item buttons in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am implementing cloth shopping website in which i am uploading cloth items with their images and description from admin panel. on home page i am retrieving all cloth items that are in stock and displaying using while loop. in order to view details i have put "view button" which on click opens modal popup and displays whole description of the item. But i am facing problem that every button of item on click only displays first item description in modal popup on all item button. I want that every item button should display item owns description. but it keeps populating first item data on every button.
Code:

```
<?php 

                $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
                mysql_select_db("login",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!"); 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_stock"; 
                $result = mysql_query ($sql);                 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
                {                          
                ?>     
<div class="grid_element"> 
                <div class="show-image">
                <form method="post" action="" id="myform" >
                <img  src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" name="image" onclick="openModal()" id="image" name="image1" target="_parent">

                <figcaption><b>Product Code: <?php echo $row['id']; ?> <br/><?php echo $row['dress_description']; ?> <br/> PKR <?php echo $row['price'];?>  </b>

                </figcaption>
                </form>


                <!-- view button -->
                <button class="update fa fa-eye" id="popupview" onclick="openModal1()"  title="View" type="image"  /></button>

 <!-- View Item modal popup -->
                <div id="mpopupBox" class="mpopup">
                <!-- mPopup content -->
                <div class="mpopup-content">
                <div class="mpopup-head">
                <span class="close7">×</span>

                <h2 style="font-family:Cooper Black;">Item Description</h2>
                </div> 
                <div class="mpopup-main" ><br/>              
                <img  src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border-radius: 25px;">
                <p style="margin-top: -250px; margin-left: 380px; "><font size="4"><b>Product Code: <?php echo $row['id']; ?> <br/>
                PKR <?php echo $row['price']; ?> <br/>
                Brand: <?php echo $row['brand_name']; ?> <br/>
                Gender: <?php echo $row['gender_name']; ?><br/> 
                Category: <?php echo $row['category_name']; ?><br/>
                Size: <?php echo $row['size_name']; ?> <br/>
                Material: <?php echo $row['material_name']; ?> <br/>
                Description: <?php echo $row['dress_description']; ?></font></b> </p>  

                <button style="margin-left: 380px; margin-top: 20px; width: 135px;" class="button button4 add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="mpopup-foot">
                <!-- <p>created by CodexWorld</p> -->
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                var mpopup = document.getElementById('mpopupBox');
                // get the link that opens the mPopup
                var mpLink = document.getElementById("popupview");
                // get the close action element
                var close7 = document.getElementsByClassName("close7")[0];
                // open the mPopup once the link is clicked
                mpLink.onclick = function() {
                mpopup.style.display = "block";
                }
                var imagess = document.querySelectorAll('button[title="View"]');
                for(var i=0, len = imagess.length; i < len; i++){
                imagess[i].addEventListener('click', openModal1);
                }
                function openModal1() {
                mpopup.style.display = "block";       
                }
                // close the mPopup once close element is clicked
                close7.onclick = function() {
                mpopup.style.display = "none";
                } 
                </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In HTML, an ID must be unique in the page. But you define the button with the ID `popupview` for each article. you need to une a unique ID for each button or use class insted

Comment: can you please edit code for id?

Comment: SO is not a code for hire site. You are encouraged to go ahead and try things as they are suggested here, reporting back as things change.